# Replacing multiple \t

Tags: c

```
    switch(start)
   {case 0:printf("");
          j=1;
          break;
    case 1:printf("\t");
          j=2;
          break;
    case 2:printf("\t\t");
          j=3;
          break;
    case 3:printf("\t\t\t");
          j=4;
          break;
    case 4:printf("\t\t\t\t");
          j=5;
          break;
    case 5:printf("\t\t\t\t\t");
          j=6;
          break;
    case 6:printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t");
          j=7;
          break;
   }
```

start takes input from user, any way to shorten this piece of code???????
Any help is appreciated!!!!!!!!

Comment: Do you know about loops?

Comment: **user253751** i know about loops

Comment: @OliverQueen apparently not. For case 0 you print 0 `\t`s and `j` is set to 1, for case 1 you print 1`\t` and `j` is set to 2, for case 2 you print 2`\t`s and `j` is set to 3. Do you see a pattern here?

Comment: Then you should be able to use a loop to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use start to compute the place in a buffer full of tabs at which to start printing:

```
if ( 0 <= start && start <= 6)
{
char* tabs = "\t\t\t\t\t\t"; // 6 tabs
  printf( "%s", tabs+6-start);
  j = start + 1;
}
```

Comment: What about 50 tabs? or 100 or 10000?

Comment: Then maybe you build up a buffer instead. I would also prefer this approach over the other answer because you avoid multiple calls to printf. This could cause multiple write syscalls (I know that printf buffers the output itself and flushes it when it's full or after a bit of time, but anyway, why rely on this feature when it's that simple to avoid such a case).

Comment: @VladRusu 1. printf("\t"); will be replaced by char function by any modern compiler.  2. It does not matter then

Comment: @P__J__ Your concern is completely right and I agree and your answer fits better in that approach but nonetheless this answer still fits as solution to the OP´s code. Quote: *"any way to shorten **this** piece of code"*.

Comment: @P__J__  of course the method works for any number of `t`'s.  Moreover, `%s` is not compulsory.

Comment: how are you going to create 10000 '\t's string

Comment: @P__J__ by using memset and malloc? Depends on what he wants.  If he has not so many tabs this method is clearly the best one.

Comment: It will be very efficient comparing to the loop. indeed.

Comment: @P__J__ If `putc` is called that's worse. `putc` will definitely make the syscall everytime it's called, or am I wrong? As per C user space code, that would be the most efficient, but the syscall takes quite some time to switch contexts.

Comment: `putc` uses the stdio buffers like the rest of the stdio output functions. In addition, it is allowed to be implemented with a macro, avoiding even function call overhead. Fir additional corner-cutting in multithreaded code, see `putc_unlocked`. In summary, there's no reason to think that it will be slow.

Answer (score 7):

```
int foo(int start)
{
    for(int x = 0; x  < start; x++) printf("\t");
    return start + 1; // it is your j
}
```

or without the function

```
for(int x = 0; x  < start; x++) printf("\t");
j = start + 1;
```